# How to calculate the final concentration of calcium ions from known starting masses of carbonate and calcium ions?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions

> If $\pu{50.0 mg}$ of $\ce{CO3^2-}$ and $\pu{50.0 mg}$ of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ are present  in one liter of water, what will be the final (equilibrium) concentration of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ expressed in moles per liter?

Comment: This is a weird question. It's not like you can just add 50 mg of a cation and 50 mg of an anion. They have to come with counterions. If $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ and $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ are the only ions in solution, then they need to be in equimolar amounts. Now, if we added 50 mg of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ as a source of carbonate and 50 mg of $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}$  as a source of calcium, then we have a more viable question. Also, have you cover solubility product constants yet?

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is weird. $\pu{50 mg}$ of calcium ion and $\pu{50 mg}$ of carbonate ion are not equimolar. However, let's assume that they have appropriate counterions somewhere. This problem can be approached two ways.

### Limiting reactant

We have a precipitation reaction between the calcium and the carboncate ions,  as calcium carbonate is nearly insoluble in water:
$$\ce{Ca^2+ (aq) + CO3^2- (aq) -> CaCO3 (s) v}$$

Convert your masses of ions to amount of substance and figure out which ion is in excess. If calcium ion is in excess, then use the amount of substance **in excess** to determine the remaining calcium concentration.
For example: Let's say you determined that your solution has $\pu{0.1663 mol}$ of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ and $\pu{0.1221 mol}$ of $\ce{CO3^2-}$. The maximum amount of $\ce{CaCO3}$ that could precipitate is $\pu{0.1221 mol}$, because we would run out of carbonate ion. Then there would be $\pu{0.0442 mol}$ of calcium ion left in $\pu{1 L}$ of solution for a concentration of $\pu{0.0442 M}$.

### Solubility product

Calcium carbonate is not completely insoluble. It's solubility product constant is $4.8\times 10^{-9}$. Thus we can set this up as an ICE equilibrium problem. I'll use the same fake amount of substances from the previous example:

\begin{align}
\ce{CaCO3 (s) &<=> Ca^2+ (aq) + CO3^2- (aq)}\\
K_\mathrm{sp}&=[\ce{Ca^2+}][\ce{CO3^2-}]
\end{align}
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
                   & \text{calcium}/\pu{mol}  & \text{carbonate}/\pu{mol}\\
\hline
\text{Initial}     & 0.1663                   & 0.1221     \\
\text{Change}      & -x                       & -x         \\
\text{Equilibrium} & 0.1663 - x               & 0.1221 - x \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{align}
4.8\times 10^{-9}&=(0.1663-x)(0.1221-x)
\end{align}

Solving for $x$ gives you $x=0.1221,0.1663$ and only the first number makes sense. In this case the final calcium amount in solution would still be $\pu{0.0442 mol}$. The carbonate amount in solution is not actually zero. It is $\pu{1.09E-7 M}$, but that is for another day.

Comment: I agree that the premise of the question is weird, but I think the question means that you have 50 mg of $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ from an appropriate carbonate source (e.g. 88.33 mg of anhydrous $\ce{Na2CO3}$) and 50 mg of $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ from maybe 273.3 mg of $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$. On a side note, if we were very particular about accuracy then we should probably worry about the $\ce{HCO3^-}$/$\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ equilibrium, but that is also for another day :)